# Graph visualization in R with three column dataframe

Tags: r, graph

I would like to plot an intensity graph in R. For example, I have the following data frame:

```
name1 name2 Intensity
A     B     0.90
A     C     0.30
A     D     0.20
B     C     0.95
B     D     0.89
D     C     0.92
```

I will like to produce a simple network graph connecting the nodes (name 1 and name 2) with an intensity above 0.9 (rounded). In the above example, it would be `A-B`, `B-C`, `B-D`, and `D-C`. I have been trying to use the package `igraph` but I find it a bit confusing.

Comment: I assume you've tried `igraph::graph_from_data_frame`? Where exactly are you getting stuck? What specifically is confusing you?

Comment: Hi MrFlick, the confusion comes from which function to use to convert the data frame into a graph object to later plot it. I guess the ```graph_from_data_frame``` is what I am looking for. I will check the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- read.table(text="
name1 name2 Intensity
A     B     0.90
A     C     0.30
A     D     0.20
B     C     0.95
B     D     0.89
D     C     0.92", header=T)

library(igraph)

df <- df[df$Intensity >= 0.85,]
my_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(df, directed=FALSE)
plot(my_graph, e=TRUE, v=TRUE)
```

[image: Network]